# Matching cells in excel based on IF statment

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Is there anyway to do what i'm trying to do here (see picture) in excel with the IF/ or statement

[image: Excel challange]

Excel code so far: =IF(OR(B4=0;C4=0;D4=0;E4=0;F4=0)=1;"False";C$1)

Comment: So your are trying to return the column header where the cell = 1?  Will there ever be a time that there are two `1`? If so what do you want to return?

Comment: Yes im trying to return header from cell 1 with the corosponding 1 in the set. There wil not be an instance of two 1's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$F$1,MATCH(1,$B3:$F3,0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Just what i need